# I can't burn a CD in 12.04. I can only read data from a CD 

Tags: 12.04, laptop, dvd, cd, burning

I can't burn a blank cd/dvd. The system does not recognize any cd/dvd drive.
When I insert a cd/dvd with data, there is no problem. The system automounts the drive.

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: How is the CD/DVD writer connected?

Comment: It's the laptop internal CD/DVD. I'm using a IBM ThinkPad T60.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using Brasero. It seems to be a regression since this error was reported before (9.10, if I remember well).

My opinion is to use K3b:

```
sudo apt-get install k3b
```

Comment: I tried using K3b. Is the same problem. It does not see the blank cd.

Comment: Please provide a dmesg output from the blank disk insertion.

Comment: When I insert a blank cd I have no dmesg output. The only output is from a data cd. In this case the output is: 'kern  :debug : [Tue Jun  5 16:47:34 2012] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 3'
'kern  :debug : [Tue Jun  5 16:47:34 2012] ISOFS: changing to secondary root'

Comment: It seems to be an udev problem. Try >sudo apt-get install --reinstall udev

Comment: It still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, from just reading through the comments, and past experiences,  I have come across this problem many times, and it turned out to be that the drive is defective.  You can try removing the drive ( see IBM website for disassembly information) dust the connector, and plug it back in.  Good luck .

Comment: The drive have two different lasers.  One that does the reading, and the other does the writing.